# Finding the unknown matrix in an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

so I was wondering how can I find the unknown matrix from an equation, I need to find X

```
    [-1 2]  X  [1 0]    [-2 -12]
    [ 0 1]     [2 4]  = [1  - 4]
```

so I started with assigning each matrix with a letter A, B, C respectively, and I have X I need to find, and I have managed to find the inverses, of all three if Its needed which I guess it is, so now what do I do next? thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$AXB=C$$
$$XB=A^{-1}AXB=A^{-1}C$$
$$X=XBB^{-1}=A^{-1}CB^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the superoperator formalism:
$$
AXB=C \mapsto (\hat {B}^T\otimes \hat A)\text{vec} X = \hat C
$$
(see [here](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~jdaunize/docs/Kronecker.pdf) for a definition of $\text{vec}(X)\;$ and here for more information: [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations))